# Проблема с клавиатурой

Tags: lubuntu

Когда я хочу ввести @ то выводится "

Так же с ~ печатает ¬

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-keyboard.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru"
        Option "XkbOptions" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp_led:scroll"
EndSection
```

Comment: Похоже на проблему с раскладкой, смените её нажав `Alt + Shift`

Comment: Не работает У меня смена раскладки на `ctrl + shift`
P.S. Сейчас заметил то что . на русской раскладке ставится / или с шифтом ?

Comment: Причем это сразу после установки

Думаю на kubuntu перейти

Comment: Можно перейти, потому что Kubuntu, Lubuntu и др. это таже Ubuntu, только с другой оболочкой.